# Is better one function with variable table/field/value, or 60 functions with variable value?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, memory

In a php/mysql project design, is it better to write one function like this

```
function getFromTableOneInt($l, $t, $f, $v) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($l, "select * from $t where $f = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $v);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $res = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    $out = array();
    while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $out[] = $r;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

where table name, field name, value, are variables, or is it better to write N functions each one with defined table name and field name?

Considering that table names and field names comes from direct calls and are not defined by user. User inputs define just the last value, the $v.

Is there some exploit on table/field name that I can't see?
Is it memory heavier to load 1200 lines of functions saeved in a php file each include? Or in php, functions declarations loads in memory just pointers?
Which one is faster or more readable, based on your experience?

Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Comment: Imho, a better way would be to use OOP (where you can extend and reuse classes), or even better than that, use some ready made DB library.

Comment: In any language I would write 1 function with parameters for simplicity, ease of maintaining and makes it much easier for someone else to read your code and understand it and support it. There should be no performance advantage either way and the extra RAM required would be negligible for the n functions design.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider writing hardcoded SQL queries or using an ORM that will build it for you securely. P.S. The method you have created is quite useless. Stick to normal SQL which is more readable and safer

Comment: "60"?  One per "second"?  "Minute"?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - For me its about extensibility and scalability. IMHO use a supported framework for this kind of thing or stick with inline SQL.

#### Frameworks

There are frameworks for this. Codeigniter, Laravel, Symfony, CakePHP and others abstract out the database functions to make them agnostic (PDO, MSSQL, MySQL users all use the same syntax to run their queries). So at any given moment you could move your MySQL DB over to MSSQL and not have to update your code. This can make the syntax more readable for most simple queries and help with things like query binding and value escaping. I have found with larger, more complex queries, these frameworks get in the way and I just want to look at a block-structured query to troubleshoot.

#### DIYs

I once was brought in to fix code like this from another dev - he had abstracted all the mysql queries in the app (as well as other tasks) to helper functions. Over time, the special conditions and special needs added up and these helper functions became quite large. What's worse was to other developers (like me) it made the code less readable. I had to go back and undo all that mess.

That's not to say you don't have a fine function there, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My conceptual problem with frameworks is this one: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6918/Codeigniter.html
You write a cloud software, and you are directly vulnerable to exploits, released or zero days, of the code you are using.
I know that for big companies or multi-dev projects is necessary. But for single man projects, I don't feel I need it.

Comment: Fair point. Not sure how CI stacks up with other frameworks security wise, but I suppose any framework is more vulnerable in certain ways. The upside is they usually patch it quickly but still you have to be ready to update when the patches are released.

Comment: @DanieleRugginenti The alternative is that you believe your own code to be more secure than that of an open source project where thousands of programmers have looked for and reported exploits in the framework

Comment: Another plug for frameworks is bumper to bumper benchmarking. With CI I can easily find the bottlenecks in my php/mysql mix, along with instant reports on every query that ran, and how long each one took. This doesn't speak to security at all, just a perk.

Comment: Install `Laravel` then open it's `.env` file, and set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` All done, now you have the most secure Web-Site in the world! (till you somehow break that security yourself).

Comment: (A move from 'MySQL' to 'PDO' does not require agnosticism, per se)

Answer (score 1):

Generalize your Database handling like opening, query and etc into a Class (not the statement).

But provide multiple methods that use mentioned general class, like:

```php
registerUser($name, $password);
findUserByName($name);
findUserByEmail($email);
```

Think about it like this: Can my single method handle all of above?
No, you will still end up writing multiple methods.

Reusing same statement and saving few bytes of memory is a concern once you write a virus (not in Web-Site's case).